# XPath to select list of nodes in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML file:

```
<RecordSet>
  <Record>
    <ID>001</ID>
    <TermList>
      <Term>Term1</Term>
      <Term>Term2</Term>
      <Term>Term3</Term>
    </TermList>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>002</ID>
    <TermList>
      <Term>Term3</Term>
      <Term>Term4</Term>
      <Term>Term5</Term>
    </TermList>
  </Record>
</RecordSet>
```

and need to parse it into a "ID-Term" file, i.e.,

```
001 Term1
001 Term2
001 Term3
002 Term3
002 Term4
002 Term5
```

Currently I have the following application:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MedlineParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse("/home/andrej/Documents/test.xml");
            // Create XPathFactory object
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
            try {
                XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("/RecordSet/Record/ID/text()");
                NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength(); i++) {
                    String id = nodes1.item(i).getNodeValue();
                    XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("/RecordSet/Record/TermList/Term/text()");
                    NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) expr2.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodes2.getLength(); j++) {
                        System.out.println(id + " " + nodes2.item(i).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the program output is currently:

```
001 Term1
001 Term1
001 Term1
001 Term1
001 Term1
001 Term1
002 Term2
002 Term2
002 Term2
002 Term2
002 Term2
002 Term2
```

Any idea what's wrong with XPath expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The XPath must take into the account the index of the `ID` node being iterated in the first loop. Your current XPath gets *all* `Term` nodes every time for each `ID` node. You should change it to something like:

   ```
   XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("/RecordSet/Record[" + (i + 1) + "]/TermList/Term/text()");
   ```
2. You have a typo in the inner `for` loop. You should use `j` instead of `i`:

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < nodes2.getLength(); j++) {
       System.out.println(id + " " + nodes2.item(j).getNodeValue());
   }
   ```

Comment: works, but depending on the size of the XML file this might not perform very well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are printing the cartesian product of all ids and terms.

This would be easier:

1. Select and loop over all Record-nodes with the XPath expression `/RecordSet/Record`.
2. For each record node, select the id (with XPath `ID`) and the terms (with XPath `Termlist/Term`), using the Record-node as context node.